# Strange notification in Iphone 4s

Tags: ios

Currently I am working on application to make and receive call. everything is working fine , excluding one bug specifically iniPhone 4s.

Steps to generate the issue :

Step 1 :When User A calls to User B (having iPhone 4s).

Step 2 :User B Without answering or rejecting call, it switch to airplane mode of network from wifi by going from setting.

Step 3 :Now User B comes back and found alert to make wifi on. and hence he press OK.

So at this point of stage User B is dis connect. Now When I force my application for background, In home screen Its show some Red color notifier on top.

I have attached an image here, Kindly have a look[image: Some strange notification Image]

So Don't know what this notification for. And how do I avoid such notifications.

This notification raised only for iPhone 4s and specifically in case when you perform all operations or steps very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the red status bar indicates that your app (in the background) is recording audio. Do you do this in AVEngineering?

Comment: thanks Tilo, I am not using any recording functionality.But yes as my application is more about making and receiving voip call, It uses Audio framework. Let me try to deallocating all Audio functionalities while network is not reachable.

Comment: Okay.. I have checked and its because of the audio session stays active while UserB's Phone ringing. But strange is .. When Phone continues to ring and meanwhile I change network to airplane mode, and come back again quickly and then when I go to background .. I forcefully deactivate the session of audio but its not getting deactivated. And as I am using the iOS5 - ARC Concept I can't make object forcefully release. And more strange is .. Its only happens when you follow steps quickly and only with iPhone 4s. Hanging my had .. not finding the issue.. kindly let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: This almost sounds like a bug - you could file a bug report.